# I cant add elements to the list - c++

Tags: c++, list

```
   void Student::addStudent()
    {
     int studentAdd;
     cout<<"How many student do you want to add?"<<endl;
     cin>>studentAdd;
     list<string>::iterator it;
     cout<<"Enter the name of student"<<endl;
     for(int i=0;i<studentAdd;++i)
     {
         cin>>studentName;
         for(it=studentList.begin();it!=studentList.end();++it)
         {
            studentList.insert(it,studentName);
         }
     }
 }
```

im trying to add string elements to list but when i try to display with another function, i cant see the elements.

```
    void Student::displayAllStudents() 
{
    list<string>::iterator display;
    cout<<"Students:\n"<<endl;
    for(display = studentList.begin();display!= studentList.end();++display)
    {
        cout<<*display<<endl;
    }
}
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: That inner-for-loop in `addStudent` is wrong. it should just be replaced with `studentList.push_back(studentName);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't loop with an iterator if you don't have element in you list. this is the error:

```
for(it=studentList.begin();it!=studentList.end();++it)
{
    studentList.insert(it,studentName);
}
```

begin() and end() point at the same element at the start.

You can use push_bask() to add elements.

Comment: add votes up if the answer is useful, is for the comunity purpose.

Answer (score 3):

At first your list is empty so Begin and End iterators are equal, so this code will not execute:

```
for(it=studentList.begin();it!=studentList.end();++it)
{
    studentList.insert(it,studentName);
}
```

If you want to add element at the end of a list just use `push_back` function. There is no need for the second loop so your code could be like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < studentAdd; ++i)
{
   cin>>studentName;
   studentList.push_back(studentName);
}
```